# RavenService entry is created each time after SaveChanges()

Tags: ravendb

I'm new to RavenDb so my question could be stupid, but I didn't managed to work it out. The problem is when I do SaveChanges, the DB entry `RavenServer` is created. I do not saving any `RavenServer` objects, it is something that happens implicitly. The object I'm saving is an `Item`, and it is saved correctly along with this misterious RavenServer. It doesn't seem like an expected thing for me.

[image]

I'd like to know what does it mean and what should I do with it? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. In Raven, you .Store(yourObj), then call .SaveChanges to save to the database. Now your object is in the database. It can be loaded via .Load.

Comment: @JudahHimango Yeah, I know, But I don't saving any RavenServer objects, it is something that happens implicitly. The object I'm saving is Item, and it is saved correctly along with this misterious RavenServer

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that. Can you show us your code?